# Convert characters like ö é ü to HTML code in PHP or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

See the following example:

```
  <h1 id="example">Ik ben één Slöetjes<h1>
```

I am trying to put strings like the  example string into a database in which i want the strings to be stored as:

```
<h1 id="example">Ik ben &eacute &eacute Sl&oumletjes<h1>
```

i do **not** want the html tags to be converted.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert characters like ö é ü to HTML code in PHP or JavaScript
**without destroying the HTML tags?**

*note: The strings i use in my application can contain spans,divs and other forms of html. I already tried htmlspecialchars and  htmlentities()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function HTMLEncodes everything that is not a-z/A-Z.

```
String.prototype.encodeHTML = function () {
  return this.replace(/[\u0080-\u024F]/g, 
          function (v) {return '&#'+v.charCodeAt()+';';}
         );
}
```

Now just try doing `'<h1 id="example">Ik ben één Slöetjes<h1>'.encodeHTML();`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something change everything to htmlentities and then undo it only for '<' and '>' characters.

Like this:

```
echo str_replace('&lt;', '<', str_replace('&gt;', '>', htmlentities($string)));
```